# Portable XML logging service (Phone, WinRT, Desktop)

Tags: c#, windows-phone, desktop, portable-class-library, windows-rt

Is there something like the [System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener.aspx) on WinRT and Windows Phone?

I'd like similar logfiles on every platform, which can be opened using the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you *could* probably write something that writes similar xmls yourself. On the other hand, I think that using xml for logs isn't very good. If there are no magic tricks, I'm not aware of, the complete xml needs to be read and parsed so a node can be added. A simple [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ms143356.aspx) should perform better.

Comment: Yes I have thought about writing something that outputs similar log infos myself. If there is no solution with portable class libraries yet we will probably implement one with an extern application to display the output with category search, different colors for different error types, etc.

Comment: Now we use log4net-similar schema with our lightweight and custom logger and desktop log4net viewer for these logs. If you prefer Service Trace Viewer, I'd suggest you to be the first and write it. No doubt your logger will be downloading like hot pies from Nuget. ;)